# Creating AppDomain using .net Framework 4 gives OutOfMemoryException

Tags: .net, vb.net, appdomain

I'm trying to create an appdomain in VB / VS2015 using .net Framework 4, 64-bit, but am getting an OutOfMemoryException.

```
domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("mydomain")
```

It works fine if I do it in a Windows Form Application, but I'm trying to do it in a class library (to be called from a 3rd-party application), and it fails every time.

I'd like to know if it is legal to create an appdomain in these circumstances (after all, I'm not creating an application), and the error message is misleading, or is there something else I'm missing (security evidence?).

Microsoft admit to a bug in Framework 4.5 which gives this error ([see this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2012/12/30/unexpected-out-of-memory-exception-in-net-4-5-applications-that-uses-custom-stack-commit-size/)), but I'm using Framework 4.

To give a bit more background, I'm using an appdomain to dynamically load and unload a dll which I am creating, so I can unload, recompile and reload during development, as the 3rd-party application which calls my dll is very slow to boot up and load documents. I'd like to get as close as possible to Edit and Continue!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and tracked it down a little bit inside `clr.dll`.
The function internally calls `GetSystemInfo` (kernel32) to check the allocation granularity.

A quick and dirty fix for this issue: Detour `GetSystemInfo`

see example code here ( I used Process.NET for the detour, it’s quick and easy)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using ProcessDotNet;
using ProcessDotNet.Applied.Detours;

namespace Bootstrap
{

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate void GetSystemInfoDelegate(ref SYSTEM_INFO info);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SYSTEM_INFO
    {
        public ushort processorArchitecture;
        ushort reserved;
        public uint pageSize;
        public IntPtr minimumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr maximumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr activeProcessorMask;
        public uint numberOfProcessors;
        public uint processorType;
        public uint allocationGranularity;
        public ushort processorLevel;
        public ushort processorRevision;
    }

    class Loader
    { 
        static void GetSystemInfoDetoured(ref SYSTEM_INFO info)
        {
            info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
            GetSystemInfoDetour.Disable();
            GetSystemInfo(ref info);


            info.allocationGranularity = 1000000;

            GetSystemInfoDetour.Enable();
        }

        static Detour GetSystemInfoDetour;
        static GetSystemInfoDelegate GetSystemInfo;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestDomainCreation();
        }

        static void TestDomainCreation()
        {
            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();

            ProcessSharp s = new ProcessSharp(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), ProcessDotNet.Memory.MemoryType.Local);

            GetSystemInfo = s["kernel32"]["GetSystemInfo"].GetDelegate<GetSystemInfoDelegate>();
            DetourManager dtm = new DetourManager(s.Memory);
            GetSystemInfoDetour = dtm.CreateAndApply(GetSystemInfo, new GetSystemInfoDelegate(GetSystemInfoDetoured), "GetSystemInfoDetour");

            var tempDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("HappyDomain", null, setup);

            GetSystemInfoDetour.Disable();
            GetSystemInfoDetour.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: You mention Process.Net, do you mean https://github.com/lolp1/Process.NET?

Comment: I'm trying to see why you have "using ProcessDotNet" ... should this be "using Process.NET"? Even then, I can't make sense of "Process.GetCurrentProcess()". Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're right. I moved the whole library to another namespace. That may as well be the reason you're getting issues with `Process.GetCurrentProcess()`. Try `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()`